# Is there a way to make a pop up show up when clicking a Radio button?

Tags: wordpress, popup

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbvPK.png)

This is the cart page of the woo-commerce website. As you can see click and collect is a shipping option. As a javascript developer, making pop-ups show up is pretty easy. However, I am not quite sure how to do that for a WordPress website. Here is a bit of the code for the radio button on cart-shippping.php:

```
                                if ( 1 < count( $available_methods ) ) {
                                    printf( '<input type="radio" name="shipping_method[%1$d]" data-index="%1$d" id="shipping_method_%1$d_%2$s" value="%3$s" class="shipping_method" %4$s />', $index, esc_attr( sanitize_title( $method->id ) ), esc_attr( $method->id ), checked( $method->id, $chosen_method, false ) ); // WPCS: XSS ok.
                                } else {
                                    printf( '<input type="hidden" name="shipping_method[%1$d]" data-index="%1$d" id="shipping_method_%1$d_%2$s" value="%3$s" class="shipping_method" />', $index, esc_attr( sanitize_title( $method->id ) ), esc_attr( $method->id ) ); // WPCS: XSS ok.
                                }
                                printf( '<label class="shipping__list_label" style="color: black;" for="shipping_method_%1$s_%2$s">%3$s%4$s</label>', $index, esc_attr( sanitize_title( $method->id ) ), wc_cart_totals_shipping_method_label( $method ), $extratext ); // WPCS: XSS ok.
                                do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shipping_rate', $method, $index );
```

Comment: You'll still need javacript to trigger the popup click event, what specifically are you trying to achieve in the php?

Comment: So I was thinking if i could open like a pop up that would show some basic warning information upon clicking the radio button labelled "click and collect". Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the hmtl window with additional shipping information in the php and then trigger the click event on the radio button to open the window with javascript / css.

I have tweaked your initial if statement and added an additional class to the input field to act as a js selector but you'll need work out what is the ID of the click and collect method or some way of targetting that specific option, easiest way is to inspect the html.

```
// set method ID for click and collect
$click_and_collect_id = 0;

printf( '<input type="radio" name="shipping_method[%1$d]" data-index="%1$d" id="shipping_method_%1$d_%2$s" value="%3$s" class="shipping_method %4$s" %5$s />', 
    $index, 
    esc_attr( sanitize_title( $method->id ) ), 
    esc_attr( $method->id ), 
    $method->id == $click_and_collect_id ? 'click_and collect' : null,
    1 < count( $available_methods ) ? checked( $method->id, $chosen_method, false ) : null
); // WPCS: XSS ok.

// add modal with extra info if id's match
if ( $method->id == $click_and_collect_id ) {
    echo '<div id="click_and_collect_info" class="poup-modal">...</div>';
}

printf( '<label class="shipping__list_label" style="color: black;" for="shipping_method_%1$s_%2$s">%3$s%4$s</label>', $index, esc_attr( sanitize_title( $method->id ) ), wc_cart_totals_shipping_method_label( $method ), $extratext ); // WPCS: XSS ok.
do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shipping_rate', $method, $index );`
```